# REST Assured and multiple posts

Tags: rest, rest-assured

I'm trying to use REST assured to test my login/logout feature. Is it possible to have a REST assured test that posts to login then posts to logout? If not, how can I test it properly?

Comment: I have looked through documentation. It doesn't give any examples or specifically say anything.

Comment: Is your auth, a basic/digest or a form ?

Answer (score 4):

Just send two **post()** with one **assert()**/**expect()** :

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.*;

@Test
public void loginAndLogout(){
    final String login = randomLogin();
    // First post to login()
    given()
    .queryParam("login", login)
    .queryParam("password", randomPassword())
    .when().post("/login/");    

    // Second post to logout() with an assert
    expect().statusCode(200)
    .given()
    .when().post("/logout/");   
}
```

Comment: In between each post, if you want to verify response then that is also possible.. i.e. after `post()` you can have `then().body("param1", "value1,", "param2", "value2", ...);`

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
expect().statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK)
    .given()
    .parameters("user", user, "password", URL)
    .cookie("cookie_name", "cookie_value")
    .post("/someURL");
```

Also there is a rest-assured auth call.

See the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/Usage) or the [examples](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured)

Answer (score 0):

Also you try this:

Create your JSON file with xyzjson name and keep your post payload data in that file and use below code.

```
Response rep  = given()
                  .headers
                  .(headers)
                  .accept(contentType.json)
                  .body (xyzjson)
                .when()
                  .post(someURL);

Assert.assertTrue(rep.StatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_Ok);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your login api call result in some sort of authentication token that is reused in subsequent requests? 
If so, I see these as separate rest assured calls to test it fully.

(Login Focus)

1. Issue a RestAssured call to the /login api. Save the returned authentication token.
2. Using the saved token, issue a RestAssured call to another api in your system that requires the authentication in step one. This confirms the authentication token works.

(Logout Focus)

3. Issue a RestAssured call to the /logout api using the saved token.
4. Repeat step two and confirm this request now fails as the login token is no longer valid after step three.