# Not able to verify the status code after login and go forward with other functionality using REST assured in junit

Tags: junit, automation, cucumber, rest-assured

I am trying to login to a website using the credentials and trying to perform other operations like a new POST call.

```
@Test 
  public void test02CheckingAccount() { 
        model.setUsername(username);
        model.setPassword(password);
      SerenityRest.given()
         .param("username", model.getUsername())
         .param("password",  model.getPassword())
         .when().post("/somewebsite/login.htm");          
      expect().statusCode(302)
      .given()
      .param("customerId", 11111)
      .param("accountType", 0)
      .param("accountId", 12345)
      .when().post("/somewebsite/services_proxy/module/")
      .then()
      .log().all()
      .statusCode(200);
```

But i am getting assertion error expectation failed.Expected status code <302> doesn't match actual status code <404>.

But if i try to remove the code after expect().statusCode(302), its working fine.

```
 @Test 
  public void test02CheckingAccount() { 
        model.setUsername(username);
        model.setPassword(password);
      SerenityRest.given()
         .param("username", model.getUsername())
         .param("password",  model.getPassword())
         .when().post("/somewebsite/login.htm");          
      expect().statusCode(302);
```

I have seen other posts and doing exactly the same but that doesnt work.

References : [REST Assured and multiple posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794952/rest-assured-and-multiple-posts)

Answer (score 0):

Hello :) this might be helpful

I use REST Assured on IntelliJ Maven Project with TestNG and can show a part of my following build up framework. I hope it might be helpful for you when using templates refering to reusable Specifications such as status validations and handling with JSON Objects due to TestNG DataProvider.

First of all, I use a rough, abstract example for Login and Logouts with imaginary URI and other content as well. I rather intent to show the main principals:

**Preconditions** for Maven Project:

- Added Dependecies for **TestNG, REST Assured**, ... in pom.xml

**Projectname**: myProject -> using 3 Endpoints as simple example.
Folder path for Json files: .../myProject/src/test/resources/loginAndLogut

**URI Login**: http://myBanking/login
Request Login: Json with two required keys for User and Password
Authentication for POST Method: **OAuth2** with Token

**URI Logout**: http://myBanking/logout
Request Logout: Json with required Key for loginToken;
Authentication for POST Method: No Restrictions

**1. Setup DataProvider Baseclass:**

Start with a Provider Baseclass in case you might have several Running Test classes which should use their own specific inherited DataProvider.
This method returns a JSON-String read from the correlated json-File in the specific folder  ".../myProject/src/test/Resources/LoginAndLogout".

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Objects;

public abstract class DataProviderBase {

    protected static String readJson(String path) {

        String requestBody = null;

        try {
            URI uri = Objects.requireNonNull(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(path)).toURI();
            requestBody = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(uri)));
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage());
        }

        return requestBody;
    }

}
```

**2. Setup DataProvider Subclass (Login/Logout):**

Now we can create a specific Provider Class for Login and Logout Testcases.
This allows us to read even a JSON File with an Json Array of where you can extract the individual JSON Objects needed for POST/PUT-Requests. Each JSONObject reflects a seperate Testcase. For example we have a specific DataProvider for simple Login check with 3 seperate Testcases:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DataProviderLoginAndLogout  extends DataProviderBase {

    private static String readJsonLoginAndLogout(String fileName) {
        return readJson("loginAndLogout/" + fileName);
    }

    @DataProvider(name ="loginExampleTest")
    public static Object[][] loginExampleTest() {

        List<String> jsonElems = new ArrayList<>();
        String jsonArray = readJsonLoginAndLogout("loginExampleTest.json");
        new JSONArray(jsonArray).forEach(it-> jsonElems.add(it.toString()));

        return new Object[][]{
                { jsonElems.get(0), true },  // Positive Case
                { jsonElems.get(1), false }, // Negative Case (Wrong Username)
                { jsonElems.get(2), false }, // Negative Case (Wrong Password)
        };
    }

    @DataProvider(name ="loginWithLogout")
    public static Object[][] loginWithLogout() {

        List<String> jsonElems = new ArrayList<>();
        String jsonArray = readJsonLoginAndLogout("loginWithLogout.json");
        new JSONArray(jsonArray).forEach(it-> jsonElems.add(it.toString()));

        return new Object[][]{
                { jsonElems.get(0) }, // Positive Login
        };
    }

    // You can add more DataProvider Methods for other Tests here ...
}
```

**3. Setup BeforeAfterRest:**

So far so good, we can finally create a simple BeforeAfter class for inheriting Sub Test classes.

```
import ... ... // Imports Hidden because to long otherwise

public class BeforeAfterRest {

    @Parameters({"systemURL"})
    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod(Method method, @Optional("http://myBanking") String systemURL) {

        baseURI = systemURL;

    // You can add Logger Functions here, but this is just rough example
    }


    protected RequestSpecification requestBodyAndContentType(String json) {

        return new RequestSpecBuilder().build().body(json).contentType("application/json");
    }

    protected RequestSpecification oAuth2(String json, String authToken) {

        return requestBodyAndContentType(json).auth().oauth2(authToken);
    }

    protected ResponseSpecification httpStatusOkContentTypeJson = new ResponseSpecBuilder().
            expectStatusCode(200).expectContentType(ContentType.JSON).build();

    protected ResponseSpecification httpStatusUnprocessableEntityContentTypeJson = new ResponseSpecBuilder().
            expectStatusCode(422).expectContentType(ContentType.JSON).build();

    protected ResponseSpecification isValidResponseContentTypeJson(boolean isValid) {

        return isValid ? httpStatusOkContentTypeJson : httpStatusUnprocessableEntityContentTypeJson;
    }

    protected ResponseSpecification logResponseBody = new ResponseSpecBuilder().log(LogDetail.BODY).build();

    protected Object getKeyAsObject(String jsonBody, String keyPath) {

        return new JsonPath(jsonBody).get(keyPath);
    }

    protected String getKey(String jsonBody, String keyPath) {

        return (String) getKeyAsObject(jsonBody, keyPath);
    }

    ...
    // Added more getKey Methods for other Types: Integer, Boolean, List, ...

    protected String getModifiedJson(String oldJson, HashMap<String, Object> modifyMap) {

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(oldJson);

        modifyMap.keySet().forEach(key -> jsonObject.put(key, modifyMap.get(key)));

        return jsonObject.toString();
    }

}
```

**4. Creating Specific Tests:**

Before implementing the Tests, we should add the requiring JSON-Files via IntelliJ in the corresponding folder "...src/test/resources/loginAndLogout/..."
For our first Test "loginExampleTest", we create a new File "loginExampleTest.json" with following content:

```
[
  {
    "username": "validUsername",
    "password": "validPassword"
  },
  {
    "username": "invalidUsername",
    "password": "validPassword"
  },
  {
    "username": "validUsername",
    "password": "invalidPassword"
  }
]
```

Now we can implement two example Tests. One for default Login and the second one for quick Login and then Logout.

```
import ... .DataProviderLoginAndLogout;
import ... .BeforeAfterRest;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.util.List;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;


public class LoginLogoutTest extends BeforeAfterRest {


    private Response responseLogin(String json) {

        return given( oAuth2(json, getAuthToken()) ).when().post("/login");
    }

   private Response responseLogout(String json) {

        return given( requestBodyAndContentType(json) ).when().post("/logout");
    }

   private String getAuthToken() {
       // ...
       // Extract Token from Endpoint for Authentication 
       // ...
       return authToken;
   }

    @Test(dataProvider = "loginExampleTest", dataProviderClass = DataProviderLoginAndLogout.class)
    public void loginExampleTest(String json, boolean isValid) {

    // Call POST Method, proof for Status depending on valid or invalid Login Credentials.
        String res = responseLogin(json).
                     then().spec(logResponseBody).
                     assertThat().spec(isValidResponseContentTypeJson(isValid)).spec(bodySizeNotEmpty).
                     extract().asPrettyString();
 
       if (isValid) {
           assertThat( res ).contains("loginToken");
           assertThat( getKey(res, "loginToken") ).isNotNull();
       }
       else {
           assertThat( res ).contains("Error");
       }
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "loginWithLogout", dataProviderClass = DataProviderLoginAndLogout.class)
    public void loginWithLogout(String loginJson) {

        // Create simple Logout Body Json with empty token.
        String logoutJson = "{\"loginToken\": \"\"}";

        String resLogin = responseLogin(loginJson).
                     then().spec(logResponseBody).spec(bodySizeNotEmpty).
                     assertThat().spec(httpStatusOkContentTypeJson).
                     extract().asPrettyString();

        assertThat( getKey(resLogin, "loggedIn") ).isEqualTo("True");
        assertThat( getKey(resLogin, "loginToken") ).isNotNull();
 
        String loginToken = getKey(resLogin, "loginToken");
        HashMap<String,Object> modifyMapForToken = new HashMap<String,Object>() {{ put("loginToken", loginToken); }}

        // Overwriting the Logout JSON with setting "loginToken" thanks to getModifiedJson Method.
        // It is more useful for huge complex JSONs when modifying several keys.
        logoutJson = getModifiedJson(logoutJson, modifyMapForToken);

        String resLogout = responseLogout(logoutJson).
                     then().spec(logResponseBody).
                     assertThat().spec(httpStatusOkContentTypeJson).spec(bodySizeNotEmpty).
                     extract().asPrettyString();  

        assertThat( getKey(resLogout, "loggedOut") ).isEqualTo("true");
    }

}
```

I hope it is somewhat useful ... My methods should be more useful when working with other complex Endpoints with partly nested JSONs ... This was just a rough simple example.